# How to replace matches in a string and index each match

Tags: r, string, substring, stringr, stringi

A particular string can contain multiple instances of a pattern that I'm trying to match. For example, if my pattern is `<N(.+?)N>` and my string is `"My name is <N Timon N> and his name is <N Pumba N>"`, then there are two matches. I want to replace each match with a replacement that includes an index for which match is being replaced.

So in my string `"My name is <N Timon N> and his name is <N Pumba N>"`,
I want to change the string to read `"My name is [Name #1] and his name is [Name #2]"`.

How do I accomplish this, preferably with a single function? And preferably using functions from `stringr` or `stringi`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `gregexpr` and `regmatches` in Base R:

```
my_string = "My name is <N Timon N> and his name is <N Pumba N>"

# Get the positions of the matches in the string
m = gregexpr("<N(.+?)N>", my_string, perl = TRUE)

# Index each match and replace text using the indices
match_indices = 1:length(unlist(m))

regmatches(my_string, m) = list(paste0("[Name #", match_indices, "]"))
```

**Result:**

```
> my_string
# [1] "My name is [Name #1] and his name is [Name #2]"
```

**Note:**

This solution treats the same match as a different "Name" if it appears more than once. For example the following:

```
my_string = "My name is <N Timon N> and his name is <N Pumba N>, <N Timon N> again"


m = gregexpr("<N(.+?)N>", my_string, perl = TRUE)

match_indices = 1:length(unlist(m))

regmatches(my_string, m) = list(paste0("[Name #", match_indices, "]"))
```

outputs:

```
> my_string
[1] "My name is [Name #1] and his name is [Name #2], [Name #3] again"
```

Comment: @BIQS Thanks for the edits, but I prefer to keep things simpler in these types of questions.

Comment: I think we disagree about what's simplest, but it's of course your right to choose in your answer. I like your approach and will probably accept it as the answer depending on what else comes in.

Comment: @BIQS Simpler as in creating fewer intermediate variables that would clutter my workspace. I agree that your edits might be more readable, but not necessarily simpler

Comment: Fair enough. I think the final answer is simple and readable, so I'm happy with it.

Comment: @BIQS check out this answer with `dplyr` and `stringr` which I think you prefer

Comment: I like it. Could you submit this as a separate answer? It's a fairly different approach and it will give a different result from your original answer in common use cases. For example, the two approaches would yield different results for the string "My name is <N Timon N> and his name is <N Timon N>, too." The base R approach would yield "My name is [Name #1] and his name is [Name #2], too." while the tidyverse approach would yield "My name is [Name #1] and his name is [Name #1], too."

Comment: @BIQS Very good point, I didn't notice myself. See my updates.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that relies on the `gsubfn` and `proto` packages.

```r
# Define the string to which the function will be applied
my_string <- "My name is <N Timon N> and his name is <N Pumba N>"

# Define the replacement function
replacement_fn <- function(x) {

  replacment_proto_fn <- proto::proto(fun = function(this, x) {
      paste0("[Name #", count, "]")
  })

  gsubfn::gsubfn(pattern = "<N(.+?)N>",
                 replacement = replacment_proto_fn,
                 x = x)
}

# Use the function on the string
replacement_fn(my_string)
```

Comment: You might be interested in the glue package: https://github.com/tidyverse/glue which has similar syntax like `"Hiya, I'm {Timon}, yo"` if I understand the vignette correctly (never used it myself).

Comment: Thanks- I think this is a good suggestion. I'd love to be able to use glue for this, but I haven't figured it out.

Comment: I think the count part would be a bit difficult `glue(gsub("<N\\s+(\\w+)\\s+N>", "{\\1}", my_string), Timon = "[Name #1]", Pumba = "[Name #2]")#
My name is [Name #1] and his name is [Name #2]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach with `dplyr` + `stringr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

string %>%
  str_extract_all("<N(.+?)N>") %>%
  unlist() %>%
  setNames(paste0("[Name #", 1:length(.), "]"), .) %>%
  str_replace_all(string, .)

# [1] "My name is [Name #1] and his name is [Name #2]"
```

**Note:**

The second solution extracts the matches with `str_extract_all`, then uses the matches to create a named vector of replacements, which is finally fed into `str_replace_all` to search and replace accordingly.

As pointed out by OP, this solution yields different results than the `gregexpr` + `regmatches` approach in some cases. For example the following:

```
string = "My name is <N Timon N> and his name is <N Pumba N>, <N Timon N> again"

string %>%
  str_extract_all("<N(.+?)N>") %>%
  unlist() %>%
  setNames(paste0("[Name #", 1:length(.), "]"), .) %>%
  str_replace_all(string, .)
```

outputs:

```
[1] "My name is [Name #1] and his name is [Name #2], [Name #1] again"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, maybe slow, but should work:

```
ct <- 1
while(TRUE) {
 old_string <- my_string; 
 my_string <- stri_replace_first_regex(my_string, '\\<N.*?N\\>', 
       paste0('[name', ct, ,']')); 
  if (old_string == my_string) break 
  ct <- ct + 1
}
```

Comment: @useR 's solution is better!

Comment: This approach works for the specific example in the question, but whether it works depends on the regex and the replacement. For example, if the regex is something like a space or word boundary (e.g. "\\w+") and the replacement doesn't delete the match, then the user will be stuck in an unending loop.